# Polarizability Tensor and Choice of Axes

Tags: electrostatics, polarization, dielectric

An extract from Griffiths Electrodynamics:

> The set of nine constants $\alpha_{ij}$ constitute the polarizability tensor for the molecule. Their values **depend on the orientation of the axes** you use, though it is always possible to choose “principal” axes such that all the off-diagonal terms vanish, leaving just three nonzero polarizabilities.

First, why does the polarizability tensor matrix depend on choice of axes?

Also, I don't see how the off-diagonal terms vanish when the axes are chosen as the principal set? A detailed explanation would help!

Comment: The components of a *vector* depend on your choice of axes. So why would you expect the components of a tensor *not* to?

Comment: Have you learned about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix? This is usually covered in a linear algebra course.